# How can I overcome the browser storage limitations and being able to store more than 500 Mb of files?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, progressive-web-apps, offline, offline-caching

I have a PWA application where the user must take several photos while offline. Those are then sent to the server once the user is online again.

How can I overcome the browser storage limitations and be able to store locally all the photos taken?

I'm currently using Indexed DB to store the files. The user will take at least 500 Mb of pictures.

Comment: Try this https://www.w3.org/TR/quota-api/

Answer (score 0):

According to browser the storage limits(quota) can vary.

There isn't any limit on a single database item's size. For example in Firefox browsers there is no limit, but there is a built-int UI message asking permission for storing single data larger than 50.0MBs. For example in Firefox you can change the quota:

```
dom.indexedDB.warningQuota
```

for Chrome you can check [this link](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage#temporary)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to changing quota messaging that the user must interact with as suggested by other answers here, you could consider alternative approaches by moving your app to node.js and using electron (https://electronjs.org/) to serve your application.

Then you could use a node library to manage your storage outside of the browser, such us with direct file storage that you can then upload when you are connected.

Comment: Given the task (taking and uploading photos) I'd be surprised if OP was only targeting desktop users.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Tarik. Unfortunately, I'm targeting mobile users.